# How to display additional info in the plugins admin table?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-list-table

When I open Dashboard-->Plugins, the page lists all of my installed plugins in an admin table.  It displays two columns: 
 'Plugin' and 'Description' ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq0MU.jpg)).  How can I add a new column to this table, and display data of my choosing?  I am aware of [WP_List_Table()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table), and have used it in the past to create a new admin table, on a new admin page.  But can I use it to modify the existing plugins table?

Alternatively, if I could add additional information to the existing 'Description' column--as other plugins do ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bUGU.jpg)--that would be acceptable.

Comment: Have you checked the answer? Did it help?

Comment: Looks to be promising, but I'll really need ~2-3 more days to have a thorough read.  I'll make sure to reply here.

Comment: Sure, take your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table of plugins on the [plugins admin screen](https://wordpress.org/support/article/plugins-screen/) uses [`WP_Plugins_List_Table`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_plugins_list_table/) which extends the `WP_List_Table` class. And there are [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php/?post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook) which you can use to modify the table columns, content, etc. Here are some of the hooks, which are relevant in your case:

- [`plugin_row_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_row_meta/) — allows you to add custom meta/content at the bottom of the "Description" column.
- [`manage_plugins_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_plugins_custom_column/) — use this to display/`echo` the content for a custom column.
- [`manage_plugins_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/) — allows you to add a custom column, but to make it sortable, you need to *also* add it using the hook below. Note: This hook is defined in [`wp-admin/includes/screen.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/includes/screen.php/?post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook).
- [`manage_plugins_sortable_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-id_sortable_columns/) — this hook is defined in the parent list table class, and the hook allows you to add a sortable column.

### Working Example

#### Preview

[image]

#### The Code

Note: The screen ID of the plugins admin screen (`wp-admin/plugins.php`) is `plugins`.

```php
// Add the "Main File" column.
add_filter( 'manage_plugins_columns', 'my_add_main_file_column' );
function my_add_main_file_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['main_file'] = 'Main File';
    return $columns;
}

// Display the content for the "Main File" column.
add_action( 'manage_plugins_custom_column', 'my_the_main_file_column', 10, 2 );
function my_the_main_file_column( $column_name, $plugin_file ) {
    if ( 'main_file' === $column_name ) {
        echo $plugin_file;
    }
}

// Add custom content in the "Description" column.
add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', 'my_add_custom_plugin_meta' );
function my_add_custom_plugin_meta( $plugin_meta ) {
    $plugin_meta[] = 'Custom data here';
    return $plugin_meta;
}
```

Comment: OK I had a look, and everything seems to do exactly what I want.  Thanks very much for all that, including the sample code--it worked perfectly and illustrated everything I need.  I was able to also convert your sample column into a sortable column, using your instructions.  So let's call this answered--thanks again.

Separately, what application do you use to create your screenshots?  I use Microsoft Paint, but yours seems to have some nicer features.

Comment: You're welcome and see [this](https://monosnap.com/) regarding that separate thing. :)